# Merge two xml files based on key field

Tags: xslt, merge, xml-parsing

I have requirement two merge two xml files. Based on the key field in the files I want to merge entire content of the xml 1 to xml 2.
Could you please help me to achieve this scenario.

I have tried this xslt but I am getting below error.
"a sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:parse-xml()"

XSLT code.

<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
<xsl:param name="XML1" />
<xsl:variable name="details-doc" select="parse-xml($XML1)" />

<xsl:template match="Key">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <xsl:variable name="Key" select="string(.)" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="$details-doc/Record/Detail[Key = $Key]" />
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

```
XML1.

<Record>
    <Detail>
        <Key>1</Key>
        <Place>Ocean</Place>
        <City>Urban</City>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <Key>2</Key>
        <Place>Road</Place>
        <City>Rural</City>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <Key>3</Key>
        <Place>Plane</Place>
        <City>Semiurban</City>
    </Detail>
</Record>


XML2

<Record>
    <Contact>
        <Key>1</Key>
        <Name>Jack</Name>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
        <Key>2</Key>
        <Name>Ethan</Name>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
        <Key>3</Key>
        <Name>Ron</Name>
    </Contact>
</Record>

And the expected output.

    <Record>
        <Contact>
            <Key>1</Key>
            <Name>Jack</Name>
            <Place>Ocean</Place>
            <City>Urban</City>
        </Contact>
        <Contact>
            <Key>2</Key>
            <Name>Ethan</Name>
            <Place>Road</Place>
            <City>Rural</City>
        </Contact>
        <Contact>
            <Key>3</Key>
            <Name>Ron</Name>
            <Place>Plane</Place>
            <City>Semiurban</City>
        </Contact>
    </Record>
```

Comment: Well, where and how exactly do you set the parameter value, to which kind of value?

Comment: Hi Martin, parameter XML1 contains XML1 xml.

Comment: You can find useful tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323750/read-xml-file-inside-xslt-and-using-that-to-construct-new-xml) : basically create a xml variable using document() function.

Comment: Show us the code that sets the parameter, it is a string with the value `XML1.xml` (you would need to use `doc($XML1)`, not `parse-xml($XML1)` in that case) or does it contain the contents of that document as a string (where `parse-xml` would work but the error message doesn't make much sense, without seeing details on where/how you set the parameter value.